# When trying to upload an image within my React App, the code does not work

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I am using Firebase to store the images. I have followed the Firebase docs, however it does not work.
The uploadImageFile starts, as I see "image upload started", but the console only shows Upload is 0% done and does not proceed further.

Also, there is delay before uploadImageFile starts running.

```
  const [imageFile, setImageFile] = useState("")
  const [percentage, setPercentage] = useState(null)
  const [data, setData] = useState({})
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0)


  useEffect(() => {
    const name = imageFile.name
    const storageRef = ref(storage, `website images/${name}`)
    const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, imageFile)

    const uploadImageFile = () => {
      console.log("image upload started")
      setShowInfo1(false)
      uploadTask.on('state_changed', 
        (snapshot) => {
          const progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
          console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
          setPercentage(progress)
          switch (snapshot.state) {
            case 'paused':
              console.log('Upload is paused');
              break;
            case 'running':
              console.log('Upload is running');
              break;
            default:
              break;
          }
        }, 
        (error) => {console.log(error)}, 
        () => {
          getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((downloadURL) => {
            console.log("done")
            setData((prev) => ({...prev, img:downloadURL}))      
          });
        }
      );
    }
    imageFile && uploadImageFile() 
  }, [imageFile])
```

**The input snippet:**

```
<label htmlFor="websiteImageUpload">upload images</label>
<input type="file" id="websiteImageUpload" onChange={(e) => setImageFile(e.target.files[0])} style={{ display: "none"}} required></input>
```

Comment: was there any error logged to the console?

Comment: There is nothing in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Are the storage settings open for reading and writing ?
[image]

If so - I'm still attaching a code that does the same thing, only in java.
I hope this will help you.

```
private void uploadDataToFireBase(Uri imageUri, String desc, String price) {
    StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("upload");
    final String randomUUid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    String imageName = randomUUid + "." + MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getExtensionFromMimeType(getContentResolver().getType(imageUri));
    final StorageReference imageRef = storageReference.child(imageName);
    UploadTask uploadTask = imageRef.putFile(imageUri);
    uploadTask.continueWithTask(task -> imageRef.getDownloadUrl()).addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            Map<String, String> itemMap = new HashMap<>();
            itemMap.put("desc", desc);
            itemMap.put("toSwitch", mSwitchEditText.getText().toString());
            itemMap.put("price", price);
            itemMap.put("imageItem", task.getResult().toString());
            mDbUser.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid()).child("items").child(randomUUid).setValue(itemMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(ItemActivity.this, "Item uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        handleProgressBar(false);
                        Toast.makeText(ItemActivity.this, "Failed to upload", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    });
}
```